# Controls messed up on rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple controller script for a character in my Unity game. 
However, when I press W and make my character turn, it's movement changes and all the keybinds are messed up. Here is my Code that turns the character:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,90,0);
```

Rest of my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour {
    public float moveSpeed;
    void Start () {
        moveSpeed = 2f;
    }

    void Update () {

        transform.Translate(moveSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*Time.deltaTime,0f,moveSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*Time.deltaTime);
        var v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        var h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (v==1)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,90,0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Transform.Translate` function moves in the object in local space by default. When the GameObject rotates, this makes the WASD key to move where the object is facing instead.

To prevent this, make it move to the world space instead. You can do this by passing [`Space.World`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Space.World.html) to the second parameter of the `Transform.Translate` function.

```
void Update()
{

    var v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    var h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    Vector3 translation = new Vector3(h, 0, v);
    translation *= moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    transform.Translate(translation, Space.World);


    if (v == 1)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
    }
}
```